# Rselenium session not created exception from unknown error

Tags: r, selenium

Through R, I ran the following script, which indicates just basic steps to open Chrome browser.

```
> library(RSelenium)
> checkForServer()
```

It produced the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
In order(as.numeric(gsub("(.*)/.*", "\\1", selJAR)), decreasing = TRUE) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

However, as usual, I thought it was just causal warning without any trouble with opening my remote driver, so I continued following steps.

```
> remDr = remoteDriver(browserName = 'chrome')
> remDr$open()
```

But it resulted in this error:

```
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
$webdriver.remote.sessionid
[1] "39f42db9-a975-4db7-87f7-b1bb51de984c"

$locationContextEnabled
[1] TRUE

$webStorageEnabled
[1] TRUE

$takesScreenshot
[1] TRUE

$javascriptEnabled
[1] TRUE

$message
[1] "session not created exception\nfrom unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': 
    {\"auxData\":{\"frameId\":\"1800.1\",\"isDefault\":true},\"id\":1,\"name\":\"\",\"origin\":\"
    ://\"}\n (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)\n  
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409699(49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393x86_64)"

$hasTouchScreen
[1] TRUE

$platform
[1] "ANY"

$cssSelectorsEnabled
[1] TRUE

$id
[1] "39f42db9-a975-4db7-87f7-b1bb51de984c"
```

I used to use Chrome several times without any problem, but after Window update it seems not to be easy to do. What did I do wrong?

When I posted this question, I received a mark letting me know that the similar question answered with practical comments was available. But it did not work for my computer(Win10 64bit).

Comment: You are running chromedriver 2.23 you may need to update to the most recent version. https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.24/notes.txt indicates that this issue has been tackled in 2.24. The startServer and checkForServer function are deprecated. You may find it easier to run a Docker container see https://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I got through it because of your anwer.